# Trying to understand __init__.py combined with getattr

Tags: python, getattr

I am trying to understand a piece of Python code.

First, I have the following file structure:

```
folder1--
   model
     __init__.py
     file1.py
     file2.py
  __init__.py
```

The `__init__.py` in the folder folder1 has nothing.
The `__init__.py` in the folder model has the following:

```
import os
files = os.listdir(os.path.split(os.path.realpath(__file__))[0])
files.remove('__init__.py')
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.py'):
        exec('from .{} import *'.format(file[:-3]))
```

With that said, I have some code in python that uses all the above
Now, I am trying to understand the following code

```
from folder1 import model as mymodel
```

My first question is what does this do? I mean model is a folder name right? it is not an object. or is it?  What is exactly importing as `mymodel` here?

then later in the same code it says

```
global args, cfg, is_fov120
args = parser.parse_args()
model = getattr(mymodel, args.arch)(sync_bn=False)
```

Apparently there is some arguments called `arch`. What is happening here and what does `model` have after this?

### Edit

When I do `print(mymodel)`

I get
`<module 'folder1.model' from 'C:\\path\\to\\folder1\\model\\__init__.py'>`

Investigating even more I can see that I have imported all the objects from the files in the folder model.

`mymodel.files` gives the list of files in the folder, and I can call `mymodel.somevariable` if some variable was defined in file1.py or file2.py. As for classes I have to create an object first like `x=mymodel.aClass()` and then I can access the elements of the object `x.someElement`.

Finally I found out that `getattr` is getting a class from the files inside model and I can guess that the `sync_bn=False` is a parameter to the constructor of that class.

So in the end, model is an object of that class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you desire to have a folder as a python module, the folder must contain an `__init__.py`, even if it is empty. Then you can import the rest.

```
import os
files = os.listdir(os.path.split(os.path.realpath(__file__))[0]) #get the folder's content
files.remove('__init__.py')                                      #remove __init__.py since it is empty
for file in files:                                               #loop through the files
    if file.endswith('.py'):                                     #if it is a python file
        exec('from .{} import *'.format(file[:-3]))              #import
```

The above code, imports every other `.py` files than the `__init__`, which is empty.

---

```
from folder1 import model as mymodel
```

Here `folder1` is the module, and `model` is the object you imported from (folder) `model` in this case, since it is now imported to folder1's `__init__.py`, and now it is part of folder1 (which is a module as discussed).

---

```
model = getattr(mymodel, args.arch)(sync_bn=False)
```

This line is equal to: `mymodel.attr`, where `attr` is the desired attribute of the object. Can you please post more code around the `getattr`, since I can't tell what `args.arch` are refering to.

As [Pyzard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13887747/pyzard) suggested, the `getattr` method gets an attribute, which is a function, since it is getting called, and method is the value that this function returned. In this case `sync_bn` is irrevelant, but knowing more about `args.arch` would still help.

---

More about the [getattr](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-getattr-method/) function, how [import](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/) works. Better explanation of how [**init**.py works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for?rq=1).

Comment: It looks like the `getattr` would get an attribute which is a function or method because it's getting called.

Comment: model is the object I imported from folder model? But there is not anything called "model" in any of the py files inside the folder model... which object are you refering?

Comment: In the first section, the code imported model/file1 and model/file2, and now folder1/__init__ contains model.file1 and model.file2.

Comment: I added a print I did